# Auto-fill google registration form with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to auto-fill google [form](https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp)  with javascript

and I found problems to fill password and confirm password field.
This is what i tried:

```
document.getElementsByName("Passwd")[0].setAttribute("badinput", "false");
document.getElementsByName("Passwd")[0].setAttribute("data-initial-value", "myPWD");
```

but didn't work

Comment: Don't waste your time, the bot detection will stop you

Comment: I only want to fill fields, not to sumbit automatically the form... it's also detect as bot?

Comment: If you are trying to populate them with values then why are you trying to set attributes? Just do `document.getElementsByName("Passwd")[0].value = "mypassword"`

Comment: because i looked that filling manually this is the attribute that changes

Comment: Thanks @IsaacVidrine, worked